# Display controls with order during For-Next loop vba

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, controls

I have a VBA application with a lot of controls.
I would like accessing the controls with an order of reading during For-Next loop.

```
' Parcours des contrôles de l'userform
For Each cCont In Me.Controls

   ' TypeName(cCont)
    MsgBox (cCont.Name)

Next cCont
```

Actually, I think I am accessing with creation date...

Do you know if I could configure the order of reading ?

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason why you would want them in `an order of reading`? Also, not sure what you mean by `an order of reading`?

Comment: I think it's about the sequence. AFAIK the `For each loop` just goes through the controls as they were added and you can't change that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Indeed it's about the sequence

Comment: If you really need to process them in a specific order, you could make a dictionary in your `For Each` loop, sort the dictionary, then do the processing in dictionary sorted order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to sort them by the TabIndex property. Set the tab indices to the desired order, then use this:

```
Private Sub test()

    Dim cCont As Control
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim maxIndex As Integer
    Dim controls As Object
    Dim key As Variant

    Set controls = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Add controls to dictionary, key by tabindex property
    For Each cCont In Me.controls
        maxIndex = IIf(maxIndex < cCont.TabIndex, cCont.TabIndex, maxIndex)
        controls.Add cCont.TabIndex, cCont
    Next cCont

    'Get controls in order
    For i = 0 To maxIndex
        If controls.exists(i) Then
            MsgBox controls(i).Name
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The posted code is a great solution, which I made workable for me with this minor change. I passed the user form, because I used the code in a module. I excluded **Label**, **CommandButton**, and **Image** in order to make Valon Miller's code work for me, otherwise the depicted runtime error would[runtime error '-2147352573 (800 200037': Member not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB296.png) show.

```
Private Sub test(frm As UserForm)
    Dim cCont As Control
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim maxIndex As Integer
    Dim controls As Object
    Dim key As Variant

    Set controls = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Add controls to dictionary, key by tabindex property
    For Each cCont In frm.controls
      If TypeName(cCont) <> "Label" And _
         TypeName(cCont) <> "Image" And _
         TypeName(cCont) <> "CommandButton" Then
            maxIndex = IIf(maxIndex < cCont.TabIndex, cCont.TabIndex, maxIndex)
            controls.Add cCont.TabIndex, cCont
      End If
    Next cCont

    'Get controls in order
    For i = 0 To maxIndex
        If controls.exists(i) Then
          Debug.Print controls(i).Name & vbTab & i
            MsgBox controls(i).Name
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

--------------------------------------------

Originally I needed a solution to get the order of sql statements synced with the order of my form controls. I wanted to do this:

```
fld1 = recordset1.value
fld2 = recordset2.value
fld3 = recordset3.value
```

was looking for a solution to get my controls and my SQL statement in order like field1 -> recordset.value1.

So instead of ordering my controls using the taborder, I created control arrays. i.e.

```
sub useControlArray()
    dim a as variant, rs as new recordset, strSQL as string
    strSQL = "select fld1, fld2, fld3 from table"
    rs.open strSQL, connection
    a = array("fld1", "fld2", "fld3")
    'This array would help like this:
    for i = lbound(a) to ubound(a)
        frm.controls(a(i)) = rs(i)
        debug.print frm.controls(a(i)) ' Form is a user form
    next i
end sub
```

This would restrict the controls to the number of controls needed to fill them using the same order as in my SQL statement and I did not need to pay attention to whether or not a control would exist.

I hope this is helpful.